# Running a javascript file within jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

I have a Jade file and want to run a Javascript file every time that jade page is accessed. How do I put a Javascript file within a Jade file so that it runs when it opens?

My code is currently:

```
doctype html
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h2 Bus Driver Location
        script(type= "text/javascript" src='/../public/javascripts/geoloc.js')
```

And then the Javascript file "geoloc.js" looks like this:

```
console.log("Works");
```

Right now, when I access the page, I would expect "Works" to be outputted on my terminal, but it doesn't. I also think my computer is accessing "geoloc.js" because in my terminal when I go to the Jade file it says "GET /public/javascripts/geoloc.js 404 65.040 ms - 1245".

Does anyone know why the Javascript file isn't running and outputting "Works" to my console? Any help, comments, or advice is much appreciated.

Comment: The path if script is correct? try /public/javascript/geoloc.js only

Answer (score 0):

In express, if public folder is static path, the correct would be:

```
/public/javascript/geoloc.js
```

Instead `/../public/javascripts/geoloc.js`

Answer (score 0):

The 404 right next to the GET request in your log line means that the file wasn't found. To fix that make sure that you've declared /public as a static file directory in your express config. you can do that by adding the following line:

```
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/path/to/public'));
```

and then you can reference your file in jade as /public/javascript/geoloc.js

Comment: I added `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use("/public", express.static(__dirname + '/path/to/public'));` to my code (the top line was preexisting in my express config). And the I tried to reference the file as /public/javascript/geoloc.js and still the `console.log("works")` doesn't output anything to my terminal

Comment: The /path/to/public portion was meant for you to replace with the actual path to the public directory. Now, the app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); line means that you are already mapping everything in the public directory to the / path of your app, so if you go to http://localhost:8080/javascripts/geoloc.js (skipping the public altogether) you should be able to see the script you're looking for (provided you're running your app on port 8080)